# How to programmatically access new Google sites content?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I see that the API exists for the old sites https://developers.google.com/sites product but that does not work for the new version of sites. Is there any guidance on what's the best way to programmatically access the content from the newer version of sites?

One idea I had was just downloading the content by issues a GET request but not sure if there's a way to programmatically authenticate for that.

Comment: The problem is that the new API is not done yet, but it is announced (no fixed date). The transition period to the new GSites ends in 2021 so thats the latest point the API will be made public.

Answer (score 0):

As DownloadPizza said, the Google New Sites API is not available yet. More information:

> [Is there any ETA for the new Google Sites API?](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/3363462?hl=en)

Also from this thread they have given some interesting information regarding New site here [Pull data on New Google Sites solution](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/21840072?hl=en)

As a summery:

The new version of Google Sites does not offer an API at the moment but Google has announced that:

- Site search (launched September 2017)
- Limit who can access a published site (launched January 2018)
- Embed URLs (launched September 2017)
- Embed Code (launched December 2017)
- More levels of page nesting (launched October 2017)
- G Suite domain web address mapping (launched August 2017)
- Assign domain custom URL (personal Google Sites) (launched August 2018)
- API capabilities including Google Apps Script integration
- Something similar to page-level permissions (Google's most recent announcement did not include this)
- Site update notifications
- Corporate themes
- More text formatting options
- Site Templates
- Better integration with other G Suite product
- New page elements, like tables of contents and image carousels
- Increased size limits
- Better publishing
- Revision History
- Editor comments
- Richer and more comprehensive search from within a site
- Google Vault support for content from new Sites

will be available - for more detailed information see  [Deprecation Timeline - classic Google Sites.](https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/classic-deprecation-timeline?utm_source=sites-help-forum&utm_medium=post&utm_content=New%20Features%20will%20appear%20in%20new%20Google%20Sites&utm_campaign=new-sites#h.p_cRwEIa-mNnew)

They offer a group you can join here: [JOIN HERE](https://groups.google.com/a/steegle.com/forum/#!forum/sites-updates/home)  so you get email notifications when new features are released. Please let us know what you think and if you feel there's anything missing let us know.